# C++14: What's difference between decltype(auto) and "auto" as return type?

Tags: c++, return, c++14, auto, decltype

I had a simple program like this:

```
template<class T1,class T2>
decltype(auto) Add(T1&& t1,T2&& t2)
{
    return t1+t2
}

int main(){
    int i=Add(1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles with clang++ -std=c++14. I found I can eliminate the "decltype" keyword as below:

```
template<class T1,class T2>
auto Add(T1&& t1,T2&& t2)
{
    return t1+t2;
}
int main(){
    int i=Add(1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Still, no problem. So my question is, when does "decltype(auto)" and "auto" differs, in different scenarios? I just guess "decltype(auto)" is designed for more complex situation when "auto" cannot work? But what is it, please kindly suggest.

Thanks a lot.